# OCaml mod function returns different result compared with %

Tags: python, operators, ocaml, modulo

The modulo function in **OCaml** `mod` return results different when compared with the modulo operator in **python**.

**OCaml:**

```
# -1 mod 4
- : int = -1
```

**Python:**

```
>>> -1 % 4
3
```

Why are the result different?.

Is there any standard module function that operate as `%` in OCaml?.

Comment: When you say you tried `-1 % 4 // 3`, does the `// 3` imply a comment, or are you actually trying to perform integer division here?

Comment: @Nick Thats the result.

Comment: I believe that Jane Street's Core library (and maybe also its Base library) includes two pairs of mod (and integer division) operator(s), and I think that one will behave as the Python operator does.  I'm not certain of that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Python is a bit different in its usage of the `%` operator, which really computes the *modulo* of two values, whereas other programming languages compute the *remainder* with the same operator. For example, the distinction is clear in Scheme:

```
(modulo -1 4)    ; modulo
=> 3
(remainder -1 4) ; remainder
=> -1
```

In Python:

```
-1 % 4           # modulo
=> 3
math.fmod(-1, 4) # remainder
=> -1
```

But in OCaml, there's only `mod` (which computes the integer *remainder*), according to this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation) and as stated in the [documentation](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html):

```
-1 mod 4 (* remainder *)
=> -1
```

Of course, you can implement your own `modulo` operation in terms of `remainder`, like this:

```
let modulo x y =
  let result = x mod y in
  if result >= 0 then result
  else result + y
```

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of modulo are linked with the semantics of integer division (generally, if `Q` is the result of integer division `a / b`, and `R` is the result of `a mod b`, then `a = Q * b + R` must always be true), so different methods of rounding the result of integer division to an integer will produce different results for modulo.

The Wikipedia article [Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) has a very extensive table about how different languages handle modulo. There are a few common ways:

- In languages like C, Java, OCaml, and many others, integer division rounds towards 0, which causes the result of modulo to always have the same sign as the dividend. In this case, the dividend (-1) is negative, so the modulo is also negative (-1).
- In languages like Python, Ruby, and many others, integer division always rounds down (towards negative infinity), which causes the result of modulo to always have the same sign as the divisor. In this case, the divisor (4) is positive, so the modulo is also positive (3).

Comment: Is the formula slightly off?
In Python, this equation `a == Q * b + R` doesn't hold. For example, given `a = -1` and `b = 3`, then  `(-1 / 3) * 3 + (-1 % 3)` equals `1.0`, not `-1` as the formula would predict. However, using the absolute value of `a` on the left-hand-side gives us something that evaluates to `True`:  `abs(-1) == (-1 / 3) * 3 + (-1 % 3) # True`

Comment: @MaxHeiber: In Python 2, `(-1 / 3) * 3 + (-1 % 3)` does evaluate to `-1`. In Python 3, if you use integer division: `(-1 // 3) * 3 + (-1 % 3)`, it also evaluates to `-1`. If you use regular division in Python 3, `-1 / 3` evaluates to negative one third (`-0.3333333333333333`), which explains why the whole thing evaluates to `1.0`.