# How can I use the normal modulo operation in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, modulo

In OCaml `-1 mod 3;;` returns `-1` but I would expect `2` as a result. Is there an other additional modulo instruction or similar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OCaml mod function returns different result compared with %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758683/ocaml-mod-function-returns-different-result-compared-with)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ocaml follows the C definition of modulo:

> When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.90) If the quotient a/b is representable, the expression (a/b)*b + a%b shall equal a.
>
> 90) This is often called ''truncation toward zero''.

Which means that it gives the remainder in the range -n+1 to n-1 or 0 to n-1. This is a unfortunate side effect of how divisions are implemented. Division is done on absolute values and the sign is corrected in the end.

To get a positive modulo you can use:

```
# let (mod) x y = ((x mod y) + y) mod y;;
val ( mod ) : int -> int -> int = <fun>
# -1 mod 3;;
- : int = 2
# 4 mod 3;;
- : int = 1
```

or

```
# let (mod) x y = let res = x mod y in if res < 0 then res + y else res;;
val ( mod ) : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

Comment: The “Ocaml follows the C definition… which means… depending on how the CPU rounds on division” part of the answer was correct before 1999, but since the C99 standard, the behavior of division in C is standardized and does not depend on “how the CPU rounds”. https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.5p6 . It was up to the compiler before 1999 (which meant that you got what the CPU did), and it so happens that the behavior that was standardized was what nearly all processors were doing, but it is misleading to imply that it depends on what the processor choses nowadays.